# How to get two action result data in one jsp

Tags: java, struts2

I want to show two action result in one jsp,such as.

```
<!--The list1Value is from article_list.action-->
<s:iterator id="list1" value="list1Value" var="value1">
  <li><s:property value="#value1"/></li>
</s:iterator>

<!--The list2Value is from author_list.action-->
<s:iterator id="list2" value="list2Value" var="value2">
  <li><s:property value="#value2"/></li>
</s:iterator>
```

How to do this?

Comment: You either use the action tag (but I'm not a fan of doing that) or you get your data in a different way, e.g., you set it up in the action that gets you to this view, and access it normally. This is a better approach.

Comment: That's means set list1Value and list2Value in one action then turn to this jsp?

Comment: Yes. Using the action tag tightly couples you to actions that may change. Presumably those actions already get their data via some sort of service/utility class, so it's just as easy to use the same functionality in the action in question.

Comment: Does this make the code messy?I already have ArticleAction and AuthorAction,so..where should i write the function that will get article list and author list together?